# Weird issue using Impala with the Hive2 JDBC drivers

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera-cdh, impala

I'm experiencing a weird behavior when trying to connect to Impala via the Hive2 JDBC drivers. I'm connecting to a cluster running CDH 5.3.6.

Basically, when performing a query like

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM old_table LIMIT 10)
```

Impala creates the table with all the columns from `old_table` but without any row. What makes the issue even more confusing is that by running the very same query with [Squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or Hue, the statement correctly creates `new_table` with ten rows from `old_table`.

I've written [a couple of small programs](https://github.com/stefanobaghino/impala-jdbc/) to test this issue. Please note that even though I'm using the wrong driver version (`hive-jdcb-0.12.0-cdh5.1`), Squirrel correctly performs the query with the exact same drivers.

Does anybody know what can be causing this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the file format used for old_table?

Comment: We tried with both tables backed by CSV and Parquet files, with the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, this particular combination of JDBC drivers and Impala doesn't work and it is not supported. If you happen to need to use them both, the only apparent workaround consists in relying on `executeQuery` calls instead of `execute` and/or `executeUpdate` (even though I haven't tested it).